# Delete feature stores. But, Continue to be charged

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I created a "Feature Store" of "Vertex AI" and later deleted it, but it continue to charge as SKU "Feature Store online serving node".

Is there anyone in the same condition?
Has anyone recovered from this condition? How?

---

I created and deleted a feature store by curl, along with the following documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/managing-featurestores

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d @request.json https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/featurestores?featurestoreId=used_apartment

$ curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/featurestores/used_apartment
```

I checked the list of feature stores list. I received an empty result.

```
$ curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/featurestores
{}
```

However, I seem to continue to be charged. (Why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overcharge should be temporary and should be reverted 2 days after deleting the feature stores. We are actively working on improving the processing so that you will not see such temporary incorrect charge in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the charge stopped during the weekend.
Past charges have also been revised.
I don't know the cause, but the problem is gone, so I will close it.